# Is it likely that there was an organic civilisation on Cyberton before the Transformers?

Tags: aliens, robots, transformers

In the Transformers movie universe, from what I understand from the first movie:

- The 'Allspark' could give machines something like a soul or free will or artificial intelligence.

From what I understand from the third movie:

- The Decepticons want humans to be their slaves to rebuild their planet (the word 'slave' is repeatedly mentioned throughout the whole series by the Decepticons)

Could we get to the conclusion that to begin with there wasn't any cybertronic life on Cybertron and there was an (organic) alien civilization like we have on Earth? However, the Allspark came from nowhere to Cybertron (or was even invented on Cybertron) and then it made machines that rose up against their owners, something like the plot of Terminator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Transformers movie mythos, the All Spark crashed into the planet now known as Cybertron and gave life to the race of Cybertronians. There was no previous race there, so there was no Terminator style machine uprising. The Decepticons need human slaves to rebuild Cybertron because it was ravaged through millions of years of the civil war between the Autobots and the Decepticons, not as a repeat of a previous cycle.